# Checking a variable

Tags: python, loops, math

Currently I have code that takes to vectors and makes a third one:

```
for b in range(2047):
    for a in range(b+1,2048):
        vector1 = (l[b][0],l[b][1],l[b][2])
        vector2 = (l[a][0],l[a][1],l[a][2])

        x = vector1
        y = vector2
        vector3 = list(np.array(x) - np.array(y))

        dotProduct = reduce( operator.add, map( operator.mul, vector3, vector3))

        dp = dotProduct**.5
        data_points = dp


       bin = int(dp/bin_width)
          if bin < num_bins: 

            bins[bin][2] += 1.0/bin_volumes[bin]
```

ps b = 36771.881
But I want to say that if (vector 3 dot product with b) is greater than (b dot product b)/2
Then vector 3 = vector3 - b

and if (Vector 3 dot product b) is less than (-b dot product with b)/2

then vector 3 = vector 3 + b

How do I add this into my loop so that it checks vector 3 for these two situations every time it makes a vector 3?

packages being used :

```
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

current code:

```
limit = 36771.881
for b in range(2047):
    for a in range(b+1,2048):
        vector1 = (l[b][0],l[b][1],l[b][2])
        vector2 = (l[a][0],l[a][1],l[a][2])

        x = vector1
        y = vector2
        vector3 = list(np.array(x) - np.array(y))

        dotProduct = reduce( operator.add, map( operator.mul, vector3, vector3))

        dp = dotProduct**.5
    data_points = dp
    if np.dot(data_points,limit) > (np.dot(limit,limit)
            dp = dp - limit
        bin = int(dp/bin_width)
            if bin < num_bins: 
            # add 1 to the count of that bin
                bins[bin][2] += 1.0/bin_volumes[bin]    
    else np.dot(data_points,limit) < (np.dot(-limit,limit)
       dp = dp + limit
       bin = int(dp/bin_width)
           if bin < num_bins: 
            # add 1 to the count of that bin
            bins[bin][2] += 1.0/bin_volumes[bin]    
   else if
        bin = int(dp/bin_width)
            if bin < num_bins: 
                # add 1 to the count of that bin
                bins[bin][2] += 1.0/bin_volumes[bin]
```

Comment: can you double check your indenting above, it looks weird..

Comment: Is there a problem in just adding the if-else statements into your code around the same area as `vector3 = list(np.array(x) - np.array(y))`? Also, are you using any packages (i.e. NumPy)?

Comment: I added what operators I'm using and fix indentation, but I'm also wondering if there is a faster way to  make it do the dot product.

Comment: if this is what my dotproduct function looks like:dotProduct = reduce( operator.add, map( operator.mul, vector3, vector3)) can you tell me what my loop should look like?

Comment: Why don't you use `numpy.dot` ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what that is could you explain it in an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two arrays `a` and `b`, `numpy.dot` returns the inner product ("dot product").

E.g.,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([4,5,6])
>>> y = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> np.dot(x,y)
32
>>> np.dot(x,y) == (x * y).sum()
True
```

Comment: This answers your comment, and would improve your code; to fix the original question, please try to tidy up your question, including fixing the indentation.

Comment: I tried to impliment your code into my program but I seem to be getting syntax errors- I edited my new code into my program, can you tell me why its not working.

Comment: I'm afraid your code is still very rough: there are missing colons, closing parentheses, "else if" (is this an elif, or an else which then has another if?). Are you using an IDE or decent editor for this? It should show you where the syntax errors happen.

Comment: umm I'm using an editor called gedit, its similar to using notpad, its a linux operator editor. and I'm sorry that I have bad syntax I just started programming a couple days ago. And I was going for an if -else - else if statement, not sure if that even works but that was what I was going for.

Comment: I use spyder, the default IDE of the anaconda distribution (and available independently too). Many more sophisticated editors will show you syntax mistakes, but you could do worse than running through the standard python tutorial.

Comment: While there are syntax errors, it's hard to say. I'm not completely certain what the code is supposed to achieve.

Comment: I want it to check the vector three that I am creating and see it fits any of the parameters that I am testing and alter it if it does meet a certain parameter which I am testing for in the if else and else if statement